# How does Flash*Freeze reduce power consumption in Microsemi FPGAs?

Tags: power, fpga, low-power, microsemi-fpga

Microsemi FPGAs are marketed as being low power. They have this flash freeze mode that is supposed to achieve much lower power dissipation, down to micro watts.

I am trying to understand how exactly does this capability help.

1. How does Flash freeze actually achieve low power?
2. How is Flash freeze used in practical designs?
3. Does the FPGA enter a "sleep" mode during flash freeze?
4. If the design actually completely stops running, and external signal is required to come out of flash freeze, how is this feature useful?

Comment: Without reading any data sheet, my guess is that's a marketing term. your answer's will vary on someone's expertise with Microsemi FPGAs

Comment: Altera/Intel have a forum. Could not find one for Microsemi.

Comment: Their tool libero also does not seem that popular. Google search using error message numbers from it yields nothing.

Comment: It reduces power to almost nothing when a device is "off" since most digital devices never truly disconnect power. Something even like a phone does not turn fully off. The CPU or power system is monitoring the power button for input, and the USB port for power actions to start charging...

Answer (score 2):

The [Microsemi Igloo Low Power design guide](http://www.microsemi.com/index.php?option=com_docman&task=doc_download&gid=132010) includes a flowchart on page 9, describing the entry process and all of its side effects. In particular:

- FDDR memory is placed into a self-refresh state and its clock source is stopped.
- SERDES PHYs, PMAs, and PLLs are placed into the lowest power state (low-power mode for PHYs/PMAs and power-down for PLLs)
- MDDR memory is placed into a similar state to FDDR.
- The FPGA fabric itself is halted, by disabling I/Os including clock I/Os. Outputs either go tri-state or hold their current value.
- SRAMs in the fabric either enter suspend mode (contents retained) or sleep mode (contents not retained), based on design settings (each instance is configured independently). Presumably sleep mode uses less energy, but even in suspend mode the SRAM's power consumption is mostly leakage.

It's possible to exit the frozen state using a number of wakeups, including RTC, and various I/O configurations. The Cortex processor (which is shut down independently of the fabric) may also prompt the FPGA fabric to exit freeze. That said, even in the case where an external signal is needed, the feature is still useful since your design parameters may include such a wake-up trigger.

Comment: So the FPGA does basically "stop running". If the FPGA is at heart of the system which means it must run continuously , it cannot just stop like that. I wonder how exactly one is supposed to benefit from this freeze mode.

Comment: @quantum231 Obviously if you need the FPGA to run continuously, you are not going to freeze it. That said, for a system that does have idle time, it will seldom run in a pure vacuum; there are often going to be external stimuli that will be used to trigger exit of the shutdown. If not, you always have the option to either exit using the RTC, or to perform your own partial shutdowns of portions of the fabric for a more modest power savings.